# Why do I keep getting the wrong output in c++

Tags: c++, factorial

```
int main()
{
int n, i, sum;

cout << "Enter a value for n: ";
cin >> n;
sum = 0;

    i = 1;
    do
{
    sum += i * i;
    i++;
}while (i <= n);
cout << "The sum of the first " << n
    << " numbers is " << sum << endl;

return 0;
}
```

whenever I run this code and use 4 as an example the output comes up as 30.  When the factorial of 4 is 24

Comment: Your logic is wrong. Instead of `sum += i * i;` it should be `sum *= i;` You have 1 * 1 + 2 * 2 + 3 * 3 + 4 * 4 = 1 + 4 + 9 + 16 = 30.

Comment: Very simply, your formula is not factorial.. You have the sum of perfect squares -- 1 + 4 + 9 + 16 = 30

Comment: are you trying to find the factorial of n, or the sum of squares of the first n numbers. Factorial n = n(n-1)(n-2)...(1)

Comment: Step through with a debugger. Take note of where the values differ from what you expect.

Comment: @DaveB yes I am trying to find the factorial

Comment: @joe you need to initialize sum=1;  not 0 (otherwise your answer will always be 0) and you need to change sum += i * i; to sum *= i; and sum is probably not a great name for the variable, product of factorial would be better names

Answer (score 4):

```
sum+=i*i
```

--> sum for first `n` squares.

factorial is

```
prod=prod*i
```